# javafx 8 error when i use onAction tag

Tags: javafx-8

I'm Really new to Java 8 just picked it up yesterday.

so Im playing around with the FX example Oracla have putout:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm

but I can not compile the source code i have pinpointed the problem to '#' events.

Error msg:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1732398722.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fxmlexample/FXMLExampleController (wrong name: FXMLExample/FXMLExampleController)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at FXMLExample.FXMLExample.start(FXMLExample.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/687048960.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/499162309.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application FXMLExample.FXMLExample
```

I think I have failed the java installtion some how. I am using java jre1.8.0_20

Comment: It looks like you just have the package name in the `fx:controller` attribute in the fxml not correctly matching the package name and/or directory structure for the controller. Specifically, the package name seems to be "FXMLExample" whereas the package specified in the fxml file is "fxmlexample".

Comment: exactly was just about to write answer sry about the bad qustion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! no problem with the java installation.

Just make sure to have the right addressing to you Controller class.

sorry about the bad question but I'm gonna leave it up, for now.